# Multiple Antidifferentiation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, polynomials

Suppose that I have the following:

$$p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n{c_kx^k}$$
$$q_M(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n{c_k\frac{x^{k+M}}{(k+M)_M}}$$

where $(k+M)_M=(k+M)(k+M-1)...(k+1)$ is the falling factorial.  I think it is clear that if we take the $M$-th derivative on $x$, the following is true

$$\frac{d^M}{dx^M}q_M(x)=p(x)$$

Suppose though that I am interested in a mapping $I:\mathbb{Q}_n[x]\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}_{n+M}[x]$ such that $I(p(x))=q_M(x)$.  THe main issue I think with the Integration operator, which would normally handle this antidifferentiation, does not yield a singlular result due to the differentiaion operation being onto only.  Clearly, I think, $q_M$ is an $n$-dimensional object but it is embedded (is this the right term...) in a higher $n+M$ dimensional space so integration $p(x)$ would yield an extra term, the constant of variation, every time the antidifferentiation would occur.

My question is; is there a way around this?  Is there a way of integrating polynomials so that we can neglect that term.  Or, probably a better way of stating the problem as above; can we find a mapping $I$ from $\mathbb{Q}_n[x]$ to $\mathbb{Q}_{n+M}[x]$ such that $Ip(x)=q_M(x)$ without just defining it from the onset and using such tools as integration multiple times?  Is there a way, perhaps, using definite integration and picking specific bounds multiple times that would negate the constant of variation once we integrated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure: use the definite integration operator.

$$
J(p)(x) = \int_0^x p(t) dt
$$
for $p$ any polynomial. This can be written out as a linear map in terms of the coefficients of $p$ (the matrix form is just a superdiagonal matrix).

Comment: So for multiple integrations just continue using different dummy variables?  $$\int_0^x \int_0^{x_1} \int_0^{x_2} p(x_3}dx_3 dx_2 dx_1$$

Comment: For multiple integrations, iterate the operator $J$, yes.That's pretty much what your formula for $q_M$ above does already. In particular, it converts the constant function $x \mapsto 0$ into $x \mapsto 0$ after $M$ integrations...which is fine, because $M$ differentiations will turn it back into..$x \mapsto 0$.

Comment: Okay.  That seems to work.  I tried to edit my post so that I could show an example, but I feel pretty confident that I understand.  Thank you.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would the superdiagonal matrix form look like?

Comment: Assuming you list your coefficients starting with the constant and working up to highest order, for quadratic-to-cubic integration, it's just $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3}\end{bmatrix}$.